# Как напечатать порядковый номер "самого длинного слова"?

Tags: c++, строки

Задан текст. Напечатать порядковый номер "самого длинного слова"

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Vvedite text: ";
    char s[1000]; //текст
    int i, len, count = 0, max = 0;
    cin.getline(s, 100);
    cout << s;
    len = strlen(s);
    int countMax = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != ' ')
            count += 1;
        else
            if (count > max)
            {
                max = count;
                countMax++;
                count = 0;
            }
    }

    cout << endl << "Poryadkoviy nomer: " << countMax;
}
```

Comment: "код не работает так как я хочу" а как вы хотите, чтобы он работал? Прежде всего, если использовать `std::istream::operator>>` для строки, то вводиться будут именно слова.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731079/c-program-to-print-the-longest-word-of-the-string

Comment: а у нас на этот счет за такое препод посылает очень далеко, как мы дефолтно пишем, так и должно быть выполнено задание, самые базовые операции только можно применять.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего скопировать все слова в вектор, а потом найти самое длинное:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), 
           std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
           std::back_inserter( words ) );

if( words.size() ) {
     auto it = std::max_element( words.begin(), words.end(),
                                 []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 ) {
         return s1.length() < s2.length();
     } );
     std::cout << "index of first longest word " << *it << " is " 
               << std::distance( words.begin(), it ) << std::endl;
}
```

[работающий пример](https://ideone.com/hMYmK9)

Comment: Вектор к сожалению использовать тоже нельзя :(

Comment: В таких случаях не в векторе хранят , а в очередь с приоритетом и сразу выводят  размер  первого, или же хранят размеры и выводят первый элемент очереди

Comment: Вы задачу прочитайте для начала, насчет размера первого.

Comment: Зачем пугаете  людей своими векторами. Видно же по коду, что человек только учится. Самые азы, возможно даже не знает что такое векторы

Comment: @StenFord ответы на SO предназначены не только задающему вопрос, а и тем, кто потом этот вопрос найдет. А писать на С++ и не знать, что такое векторы...

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s, max;
    int maxi = -1;
    for(int i = 1; cin >> s; ++i)
        if (s.length() > max.length())
            max = s, maxi = i;

    cout << maxi << ": " << max << endl;
}
```

Завершается ввод с помощью Ctrl+Z в Windows (кажется, Ctrl+D в Linux).

Comment: Красиво, только по моему нужно выделять из строки слова, а не вводить слова отдельно. Или я ошибаюсь?...

Comment: В условии этого не было :) Но... `cin.getline(s, 100); istringstream c_in(s);` и заменить `cin>>` на `c_in>>` :)

Comment: Да, это один из вариантов

Answer (score 0):

Все можно сделать и методами `std::string;` Находим в строке следующий пробел, размер от начала и до этого места,  разница позиций и будет длина слова(выполняем сравнения длин).  Находим следующий непробел, и оттуда делаем то же самое по циклу, пока не достигнем конца строки

```
std::string s;
getline(std::cin, s);
size_t  first = 0, last = 0,
        word_size = 0, index = 0, size = s.size();

for (int i = 1; first < size; ++i) {
    last  = s.find(' ', first);
    if (last == std::string::npos)
        last = size;
    // размер слова
    size_t sz = last - first;
    if(word_size < sz) {
        word_size = sz;
        index = i;
    }
    first = s.find_first_not_of(' ', last);
}
std::cout << index;
```

Для С массивов та же логик, только используется `strtok`

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что ваше знание C++ ограничивается за редким исключением конструкциями, перешедшими из C в C++. А поэтому вы не можете использовать стандартные классы. конструкции и стандартные алгоритмы из C++ такие, как, например, `std::string` или `std::istream_iterator`.

Сразу же замечу, что если у вас имеется символьный массив, то вам нет никакой необходимости создавать еще промежуточный контейнер такой, как, например, `std::vector`, как некоторые здесь предлагают.

Ваша задача может быть легко решена, используя лишь стандартные строковые C-функции. Я предполагаю, что словом считается набор любых символов, ограниченных либо символом пробела, либо табуляции.

Ниже представлена соответствующая демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 1000;
    char s[N];

    std::cout << "Enter a text: ";
    if ( not std::cin.getline( s, sizeof( s ) ) ) s[0] = '\0';

    size_t count = 0, max_length = 0;

    const char *blank = " \t";

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( const char *p = s; *( p += std::strspn( p, blank ) ); i++ )
    {
        auto length= std::strcspn( p, blank );

        if ( max_length < length )
        {
            max_length = length;
            count = i;
        }

        p += length;
    }

    std::cout << "\nThe number of the maximum word with length equal to "
              << max_length << " is " << count << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть, к примеру, следующим образом:

```
Enter a text: Some sequence of words entered by the user

The number of the maximum word with length equal to 8 is 1
```

И, действительно, самое длинное слово в введенном предложении - это слово `"sequence"`, которое содержит `8` символов и имеет порядковый номер **1**, если начинать индексацию слов с `0`.

Если хотите, чтобы индексация слов для непустого ввода начиналась с `1`, то предложение вывода в программе замените на следующее предложение

```
std::cout << "\nThe number of the maximum word with length equal to "
          << max_length << " is " << ( max_length == 0 ? count :count + 1 ) 
          << '\n';
```

Тогда вывод результата на консоль для предыдущего примерного запуска программы будет выглядеть как

```
The number of the maximum word with length equal to 8 is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "string.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Vvedite text: ";
    char s[1000]; //текст
    int i, len, count = 0, max = 0;
    cin.getline(s, 100);
    cout << s;
    len = strlen(s);
    int countMax = 0, currentWord = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != ' '){
            count++;
        }
        else
            currentWord++; //меняем номер слова
            if (count > max)
            {
                max = count;
                countMax = currentWord; //текущий номер слова с макс. длиной
                count = 0;
            }
    }

    cout << endl << "Poryadkoviy nomer: " << countMax + 1; //отсчет ведется от 1
}
```

Чуть чуть переделал ваш код. Проблема была в том, что вы меняли countMax только когда находил слово с макс. длиной. А нужно его менять каждый раз после пробела, чтобы знать текущий номер.